# How to sum a non-persistent attribute in a group clause

Tags: sum, grouping, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a TourDet model which has amongst others the following persisted attribs:

```
tdclientid
tdsuppid
tdpaxnos
tdpriceperpax
```

I also have the following in TourDet class

```
def tourval
  tdpaxnos * tdpricerperpax
end
```

I am now trying to do the following:

```
 tdis = TourDet.find(:all, conditions: ['tdtourhdrid = 23'], group: [:tdsuppid,:tdclientid], select: ['tdsuppid,tdclientid,sum(tourval) as ttl'])
```

However rails complains of Unknown column 'tourval'.

Any ideas on how I can achieve the same result in another way?

I'm using Rails 3.2 with Ruby 1.9 and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your app, you can't refer to `tourval` in your query, as it's defined in the Ruby, not in MySQL.

How about this?

```
tdis = TourDet.find(:all, conditions: ['tdtourhdrid = 23'], group: [:tdsuppid,:tdclientid], select: ['tdsuppid,tdclientid,sum(tdpaxnos*tdpricerperpax) as ttl'])
```

Comment: I knew I'd run into problems with my example.  The truth is that valexcvat is a 'complex' calculation and depends on pulling data from other models to provide exact business rules.  I just used it to simplify the question.  I really do need to somehow use the defined calculation and sum on that.